# Return all rows indexed by FullText

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

In SQL Server 2008, I have `OneTable` that contains `OneTextColumn` that was full-text indexed.

Is there a way to find out what records of `OneTable` DID result in at least one record in the full-text index?

OR

Is there a way to find out what records of `OneTable` DID NOT result in at least one record in the full-text index?

Comment: Would you like to explain what exactly you mean by `a record of OneTable result in at least one record in the full-text index` ?????

Comment: @M.Ali - The full-text catalog is built analyzing the content of OneTextColumn and a key index of OneTable is kept in the catalog index if the text can be indexed. When you search for "text" with CONTAINS(*, '"text"'), the fulltext index will return matches based on what rows match your filter. I am looking for a way to find the rows that will never be a match, because they are not in the catalog (OneTextColumn might me empty or it might have a non-indexable content ... )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PK_ID FROM Table_Name 
EXCEPT 
SELECT PK_ID FROM Table_Name  
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Text')
```